# using multiple functions in a fstream/ifstream file?

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, edit, fstream

I've been browsing the web for hours hoping I can answer this question. I'm a C++ beginner and  working on a program that reads a txt file and performs some functions to modify it. So far it can read and run the first function but functions after that cannot read the file/get executed. I've tried passing it as a reference and checking the functions for errors but so far only one function is executed regardless of the order.

Here is my code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
//Reading and processing the text file
fstream text_file;
text_file.open (argv [2], ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);

if (!text_file.is_open())
{
    cout << "File is not open! " << endl;   //Checks whether the file is open
}
else 
{
toAlpha (text_file);        //This function executes
printFile (text_file);      //This doesn't

checkDictionary (text_file, Dictionary, Spelling);  //same for this one 
text_file.close ();
}
```

here is one of the functions I'm using that don't get executed

```
//Prints off the lines read in the txt file 
    void printFile (fstream& text_file)
    {
        string word;
        while (getline (text_file, word))
        {
            cout << word << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably your first function reads the file to EOF so there is nothing to get in `printFile()`

Comment: You've made a critical mistake in your debugging, here. You _assume_ that `printFile` is not executed at all, but you never prove it and, in fact, you're wrong. You should have put debug output inside `printFile` to show that the function is called just fine... it's the _contents_ of the function that are the problem. I'm interested to hear what you meant by _"checking the functions for errors"_, since you have no error checking in `printFile`; if you had error checking around the stream in `printFile`, you'd have found the problem quite quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Reset the file pointers and clear flags

```
toAlpha (text_file); 
text_file.seekg(0) ; 
text_file.clear();
printFile (text_file);   
text_file.seekg(0) ;
text_file.clear();
checkDictionary (text_file, Dictionary, Spelling);
```

Comment: @user3807849 Why doesn't they work ? First you need to understand how file I/O operation works, try `std::cout` in called routines, see if the stream is in good state, where does it points, etc. The suggested snippet should eventually make it work

Comment: Thanks for the comments. However, I tried the implementation you suggested and neither the printFile () and checkDictionary () work. I added some couts in the functions for debugging:                         void printFile (fstream& text_file)
{
  if (!text_file.eof () )
 {
  cout << "error in reading the file" << endl;
 }
 string word;
 cout << "before the while printFile" << endl;               both messages appear when I run the program which, makes me think the files cannot be read by the functions.

Comment: @user3807849 Check the stream states, refer [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/), use `print_state` function, you'll see the problem

Comment: That was very useful. apparently the file is not been read by the program. I'm still trying to figure out the reason this is happening. Do I need to open the file again once it reaches to the end of the reading/input operation??. Here is the output of the print_state function: